# Android App Deeplinking using assetlinks.json

Tags: android, applinks

I am trying to link my app to url, so that it will open the app directly without selector option.

I added below code in android manifest file
but still it is not opening app directly.

```
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="domain.com" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="domain.com" />
        </intent-filter>
```

After app installation I check I ran below command

```
adb shell dumpsys package domain-preferred-apps
```

but still it is showing status `undefined` for my app package.

```
  Package: <"package name">
  Domains: <"domain.com">
  Status:  undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the Manifest is only half of this process — you also need to do some configuration on your server so that Android can link the two together.

[This article](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-set-up-android-m-6.0-marshmallow-app-links-with-deep-linking) explains the steps. Basically you need to create an **applinks.json** file with your SHA256 fingerprint and then serve that over HTTPS from your domain without any redirects.